# Initialize only first argument of c++11 tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, stdtuple

Minimal working example:

```
#include <tuple>

struct example
{
    example(int, char) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::tuple<example, int, double>
        my_tuple(example(0, 'x'), 42, .0);
    // std::tuple t = make_my_tuple(0, 'x');
    return 0;
}
```

This works.

Is there a more elegant way to initialize only the first member, like I sketched in the comment? One which **only takes the arguments to construct the first tuple member and does not initialize the others**?

The reason I ask? I am just interested in the semantics of the language.

Comment: how should tuple know the second param is 42?

Comment: @itwasntpete I don't want to initialize the second and third param yet.

Comment: ok, but should the first parameter be a **example**?

Comment: You can assume that it is always of type `struct example` for now, yes.

Comment: Are you saying you *want* to carry outright-*indeterminate* values for all members of the tuple *except* the first one? if so, I'm not seeing how you're going to use a tuple to do it (without crafting your own, anyway). At minimum std::tuple will value-initialize unspecified members and I'm not seeing any way you're going to side step that (at least not obviously), not that I can fathom a reason you would want to.

Comment: the usual implementation of tuple is on stack, and variables on stack **have to** be initialized, at least by the compiler. i guess what you want is not possible.

Comment: maybe [this](http://theotherbranch.wordpress.com/2012/11/19/generalised-type-deduction-for-class-template-instance-construction/) could help you.

Answer (score 2):

You say that giving values for the other two members is not necessary - are you worried about performance? Or that there may be no suitable value for these members?

If it's the latter, you could have your tuple hold boost::optionals. e.g.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

using namespace boost;

struct example
{
    example(int, char) {}
};

typedef std::tuple<example, optional<int>, optional<double>> MyTuple;

int main()
{
   MyTuple my_tuple(example(0, 'x'), optional<int>(), optional<double>());
   return 0;
}
```

You now semantically have the int and float "uninitialised", and can query their value as such.

To make this more elegant, you can wrap this into a function, using the perfect forwarding idiom for the arguments (in general; in this case your arguments are cheap to copy, so no speed benefit from doing this):

```
template <class... Args>
MyTuple make_mytuple(Args&&... args)
{
    return MyTuple(example(std::forward<Args>(args)...), optional<int>(), optional<double));
}
```

The advantage of this template is that it's resilient to changes in example's constructor. If you add another argument, just call make_mytuple with the new arguments and it will work.

Your other point about the copying in the tuple construction is valid, but in reality I believe this will be optimal on most compilers. (a combination of RVO and elision of copies when passing an rvalue to a function by value).

Comment: Thanks, but I do not worry about finding good starting values. I just want the constructor be callable more "comfortable".

Comment: Ok, thanks, though it still does unnecessary initialization for the 2nd and 3rd member. But at least, it helped formulate the question. :)

Comment: It does, but with optional, the default initialisation costs the same as initialising a boolean, so if you were to use types that were more costly to initialise than an int or double, it would be fast. Plus it gives you the semantics to ask "is this element initialised?"

Answer (score 1):

You can use uniform initialization. Sadly, you cannot define a default value, argument will be initialized with the default constructor or 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

enum class Result {Full, Partial, Empty};
std::tuple<bool, int, double> get_tuple(Result type)
{
    if (type == Result::Full)
        return {true, 42, 3.14159};
    else if (type == Result::Partial)
        return {true, 42, {}};
    else
        return {};
}

int main()
{
    bool b;
    int i;
    double d;

    std::tie(b, i, d) = get_tuple(Result::Full);
    std::cout << b << " " << i << " " << d << std::endl;

    std::tie(b, i, d) = get_tuple(Result::Partial);
    std::cout << b << " " << i << " " << d << std::endl;

    std::tie(b, i, d) = get_tuple(Result::Empty);
    std::cout << b << " " << i << " " << d << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1 42 3.14159
1 42 0
0 0 0
```